# Application.Exit and stopping a running System.Windows.Forms.Timer in a form

Tags: winforms, timer

If I call Application.Exit from my Winforms app in a form which has a running System.Windows.Forms.Timer, then will the timer also be stopped automatically?

```
 public void StartProcessing()
    {

        int i = 0;

        while (true)
        {
            if (BatchNumbersQueue.Count > 0)
            {
                i = BatchNumbersQueue[0];
            }
            else
            {
                //stop the time that queues batches  and exit
                timer1.Stop();
                Application.Exit();
            }
            ProcessQueue();
            QueueOfBatches.RemoveBatchToQueue(i);
            i = 0;
        }
    }
    //timer tick event
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        UpdateProcessingQueue();
    }
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure that `Application.Exit()` stops all operations and then gracefully exits.

Comment: @Evanlewis Except that the form closing events don't fire. See [Tip: Use Form.Close() opposed to Application.Exit()](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tom_krueger/archive/2005/02/24/379678.aspx).

Comment: @LarsTech Take a look at MSDN Documentation for `Application.Exit()` [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx).  It clearly states that form closing events are raised.  Unless i'm reading this wrong...

Comment: @Evanlewis I stand corrected.  (Sitting actually).

Comment: @LarsTech Standing in front of SO is too hardcore ;)  BTW I do agree that `Form.Close()` is probably a bit cleaner in most cases.

Comment: @Evanlewis - Hans Passant had answered one of my questions recently whilst stating that a form should be exited by setting its `DialogResult` and not by using `form.Close()`, not found out the exact science behind it yet but it seems to be working better for me

Comment: @Sayse That's interesting, I will take a look at that. Thanks!

Comment: @Evanlewis - ["You can use this property to determine how a dialog box is closed in order to properly process the actions performed in the dialog box."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I am quoting directly from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157894.aspx) here

> The Exit method stops all running message loops on all threads and closes all windows of the application. This method does not necessarily force the application to exit. The Exit method is typically called from within a message loop, and forces Run to return.
>
> To exit a message loop for the current thread only, call ExitThread.
>
> Exit raises the following events and performs the associated conditional actions:
>
> A FormClosing event is raised for every form represented by the OpenForms property. This event can be canceled by setting the Cancel property of their FormClosingEventArgs parameter to true.
>   If one of more of the handlers cancels the event, then Exit returns without further action.
>
> Otherwise, a FormClosed event is raised for every open form, then all running message loops and forms are closed.

In other words calling `Exit()` will definitely stop and dispose of your `Timer` object.